# Nexus 7 and ethernet connection

Tags: nexus-7, connection-issues

In places where there's no wi fi, wired internet connection is sometimes available. But reading around it seems there's a bug in my Nexus 7 (2013) - Android updated to 4.4.2 - that prevents an ethernet connector from working.

Is this correct? Has there been any response from Google about it - a firmware fix? I'm not really up to doing my own patching.

Answer (score 0):

Many people have reported that [Plugable's adapter](http://plugable.com/products/usb2-otge100) works.